# Android menu item text color in theme

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme, android-styles

I am designing a new theme for my android app using Android Studio Theme editor.

I have not been able to change the text color of the options menu text color.

I have since tried editing the xmls and nothing has worked to change the option items menu.

I have used the following lines in all my styles.xml with no changes...None of the lines with the word text in them have any effect on the menu item text color.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_pressed</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_color_primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/text_color_secondary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/text_color_secondary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/text_color_inverse</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_primary</item>
</style>
```

The entire application code base can be viewed here...

Comment: Are you sure that you are editing the correct styles and it matches with the parent of your app theme ?

Comment: Yes it is the correct theme that the app is loading. The theme editor does not even give an option to edit menu item text color. Nor does it give the option to edit dialog background color. Is it because my parent theme does not change those color???

Comment: Can you please post your styles file if its not too big ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to your custom theme:

```
<item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/MenuItemTextAppearance</item>
```

And then create a new style:

```
  <style name="MenuItemTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item> // replace this value with your desired menu item color.
  </style>
```

Comment: Where does the new style go? In the styles.xml or its own file?

Comment: just put it in the styles.xml.

Comment: also, have you considered using the AppCompat design library?

Comment: I want to help you but you are going to have to respond to the questions.

Comment: I have added a link to my application source in original post.

Comment: On line 11 of styles.xml, it says:


<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">


but it should read "parent = "android:Theme.Material.Light"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124952/discussion-between-rustwebdev-and-scottf).

Comment: yes, if I have been of any help to you please accept my original answer as "best answer" and upvote any of my posts/comments to your hearts content, I'd appreciate it! and I will continue to see if there are any known bugs with 5.0.1. if so ill let you know

Comment: This works for me , by adding the style in android:popUpTheme style

Answer (score 3):

Add this line on your theme

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/your_color</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are editing the wrong attribute, can you please try the following ?

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">yourColor</item>
```

Please refer the above code for API>=21

```
<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>
```

Please refer the above code for API < v21

Hope your issue is solved.

You can also refer [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html?m=1)

Comment: This not not help, as I have tried those value, and the top one is even currently present.